# Blazor equivalent to OnActionExecuting?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-core-3.0

In my MVC controllers, I would overload the `OnActionExecuting` method to check for security rights accessibility. Is there an equivalent to this behavior in Blazor serverside when routing to razor pages without controllers?

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    if (!context.IsAuthorized(out string message))
        context.Result = StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, 
message);
    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
}
```

Comment: > “I would overload the OnActionExecuting method to check for security rights“ - this is what authorisation filters are for.

Comment: Is there an equivalent to that that I can add into my razor pages?

Comment: Be very careful that MVC is executing in the server (so it's under your control) and Blazor is executing on the client (so the code can be hacked). Do not trust the client to check for access permissions, it can be bypassed.

Comment: @Jordi I am not using WebAssembly Blazor. It's server side Blazor which uses SignalR and all executes server side for me

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure if this is the best way to solve this, (I would love to know if it is), I have found a workaround and hopefully this can help someone else as well

I intercepted the `Found` method of the `Router` as so:

```
@inject IUserContext User

<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        @if (routeData.IsAuthorizedFor(User, out string message))
        {
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(MainLayout)" />
        }
        else
        {
            <LayoutView Layout="typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>@message</p>
            </LayoutView>
        }
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

The reason I don't think this is optimal is because this doesn't seem like the type of code that should go in a razor file. The `Router` methods were not virtual either, because I did consider creating my own router type inheriting from that one.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Blazor .NET 5 from the base class (i.e. the .cs file, not the .razor file. I didn't try from .razor file).

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace YourProjectName.Pages
{
    public class YourRazorFileName: ComponentBase
    {
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            base.OnInitialized();
           //Insert things you want to run on initialize here
        }
    }
}
```

Other similar methods: OnAfterRender, OnParametersSet. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.onafterrender?view=aspnetcore-5.0